# prove that a function is continuous with respect to metric

Tags: metric-spaces

> Prove that the multiplication function $m : \mathbb{R}^2 → \mathbb{R}$, defined by $m(x, y) = xy$, is continuous with
>   respect to the Euclidean metric $d_2$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the usual (also Euclidean) metric on $\mathbb{R}$.
>   HINT: pass to an equivalent metric.

a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is $(d_X, d_Y)$ continuous if for all $a \in X, \epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $$d_X (x, a) < \delta \Rightarrow d_Y (f(x), f(a)) < \epsilon$$

so since $d_2$ is strongly equivalent to $d_\infty$, i want to prove that $d_\infty (p, q) < \delta \Rightarrow d_2 (m(p), m(q)) < \epsilon$ for points $p=(a, b)$ and $q=(x, y)$, but i don't know how to start

Answer (score 1):

We have 
\begin{align*}
d_{1}(m(x,y),m(a,b))&=d_{1}(xy,ab)\\
&=|xy-ab|\\
&=|xy-xb+xb-ab|\\
&\leq|x||y-b|+|b||x-a|\\
&\leq(|x|+|b|)(|x-a|+|y-b|)\\
&\leq(|x|+|b|)\left(\sqrt{|x-a|^{2}+|y-b|^{2}}+\sqrt{|x-a|^{2}+|y-b|^{2}}\right)\\
&=2(|x|+|b|)d_{2}((x,y),(a,b))\\
&\leq 2(|x-a|+|a|+|b|)d_{2}((x,y),(a,b))\\
&\leq 2(d_{2}((x,y),(a,b))+|a|+|b|)d_{2}((x,y),(a,b)).
\end{align*}
Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta=\min\{1,\epsilon/(2(1+|a|+|b|))\}$, then it is routine to check that $d_{2}((x,y),(a,b))<\delta$ implies that $d_{1}(m(x,y),m(a,b))<\epsilon$.

Comment: this is similar to the answer in the notes i'm using but i don't understand what process i should use to find $\delta$ in a question like this. what should i be looking for? i can never come up with the solution by myself

Comment: I have written there for the $\delta$.

Comment: but how did you determine it in the first place? i can follow your answer but why do you choose $\delta=\min\{1,\epsilon/(2(1+|a|+|b|))\}$?

Comment: All these questions you need to do it backwardly, that is, we estimate $d_{1}\leq\cdots\leq Cd_{2}$ for some constant $C>0$, because we want something like $<\epsilon$, so just let $Cd_{2}<\epsilon$, and hence the $\delta>0$ is then taken as $\epsilon/C$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\{x_{n}\}$ and  $\{y_{n}\}$ are two sequences  of real numbers converging to x ,y  $\in \mathbb{R} $ respectively then the sequence $\{x_{n}y_{n}\}$ converges to xy. Now one can use the sequential criterion for continuity to prove that m is continuos .